# How to search for a keyword in DevTools JavaScript debugger?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

How to search for a keyword in the DevTools JavaScript debugger, as below:

[image]

It seems there are no such option in the pop up menu. Search on google also not brings related results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can search a single file the usual way using Ctrl+F. You can search many by using the tree view; right-click the level you want and choose "Search in all files."

Answer (score 2):

It's just like when on a page - pressing Control-F while a source file is focused will let you search for words in that source file.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much